# remove background with feh?

Tags: x11, wallpaper, feh

I use feh to set fixed background (wallpaper) in X (one line in .xinitrc):

```
feh  --bg-fill --no-fehbg some_image_file &
```

Is this possible to remove background using feh (or any other tool/command) during X session?

I know that I can use some kind of dummy image like black.png but I'd rather prefer not creating additional file for such a simple task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xsetroot` allows you to specify greyscale or solid colour backgrounds.